# Add attributes to bundle-product options

Tags: magento2, product-attribute, bundled-product

How can I display custom product attributes for bundled products options?

Products that are used as bundle-option are not fully loaded, so i cant access all/custom attributes. (Right?)

E.g. I'd like to display short description or thumbnail image or custom attributes ...

I guess this could be possible via XML, but im happy with every idea, that does not use `load(option-product)` to get custom attributes.

<sup>(sorry, still a M2 newbie)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

##### Custom bundle option attributes

You can set them up by setting your custom attribute to "Used in Product Listing": "Yes"

Then load that attribute in the bundle option template with `$selection->getYourAttribute()`

The bundle option template depends on your FE theme (e.g. `/Magento_Bundle/templates/catalog/product/view/type/bundle/option/checkbox.phtml`)

Answer (score -1):

1)Create a InstallData.php file with following code

```
<?php
namespace vendor\module\Setup;

use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetup;
use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;

class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface
{
    private $eavSetupFactory;

    public function __construct(EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory)
    {
        $this->eavSetupFactory = $eavSetupFactory;
public function __construct(EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory)
    {
        $this->eavSetupFactory = $eavSetupFactory;
    }
    
    public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);
        $eavSetup->addAttribute(
            \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY,
            'sample_attribute',
            [
                'type' => 'text',
                'backend' => '',
                'frontend' => '',
                'label' => 'Sample Atrribute',
                'input' => 'text',
                'class' => '',
                'source' => '',
                'global' => \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
                'visible' => true,
                'required' => true,
                'user_defined' => false,
                'default' => '',
                'searchable' => false,
                'filterable' => false,
                'comparable' => false,
                'visible_on_front' => false,
                'used_in_product_listing' => true,
                'unique' => false,
                'apply_to' => ''
            ]
        );
    }
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Sry, this does not anser how to display custom attributes for bundle-product options.